# I want to Add Value to a Drop down list if i choose a specific value in another drop down list

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I have a drop down list that contains the name of some products, i want to show another drop down list (for size, S,M,L) if the user chooses a specific product and i don't want to add it to the other values(products) because they don't have sizes

```
    <label>Product:</label> <select name="product">
        <option value="1">Paper</option>
        <option value="2">Bags</option>
        <option value="10">Backpacks</option>
        <option value="3">something something</option>
        <option value="4">some other thing</option>
        <option value="20">brand bags</option>
        </select>

        <select name="size3">
        <?php  
        if($_POST['product']=="10" || $_POST['product']=="20"){
            echo   "<option value=`1`>Small</option>".
                    "<option value=`2`>Medium</option>".
                    "<option value=`3`>Large.</option>";
            }
        ?>
        </select>
```

When it comes to the output the dropbox actually have the values that i want but that is after i choose **THE** specific value and **refreshes** the page

Comment: Well if you don’t want to reload the page first, then you either need to do this using an AJAX request (send the value from first selecf field to the server, get HTML code or the data to build the second one back and modify the current document) - or you simply show/hide the already existing second select field on the client side using JavaScript.

Comment: Well, the project that i am working on right now doesn't allow me to use anything but php and html and i don't even have any experience working with javascript or ajax, so if there is any other way

Comment: Not really. If you are limited to HTML & PHP, then you _have to_ submit the form, before you can access the values on the server side.

Comment: without ajax or JS i dont see way this to be done without refresh page

Comment: If you want to only use PHP then split your application into 2 pages - first page handles the _product_ and the 2nd page uses the selected product to show the available _sizes_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set a listener in javascript on the main select and then hide or show the size select
You can do a lot in javascript before sending the result to the back

```js
       let el = document.getElementsByName("product");
       let target = document.getElementById("size3");
       el[0].addEventListener("change",function(){
            let choice = this.value;
            if(choice == "20" || choice == "10"){
                target.style.display="inline-block";
            }else{
                target.style.display="none";
            }
        });
```

```html
        <label>Product:</label> 
        <select name="product">
          <option value="1">Paper</option>
          <option value="2">Bags</option>
          <option value="10">Backpacks</option>
          <option value="3">something something</option>
          <option value="4">some other thing</option>
          <option value="20">brand bags</option>
        </select>

        <select name="size3" id="size3" style="display:none;">
              <option value="1">Small</option>
              <option value="2">Medium</option>
              <option value="3">Large</option>
        </select>
```